# Why is NHibernate PrepareQuery taking so much time?

Tags: performance, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate Session.Query() method to get some data from a sql db. Recently i noticed the query is taking over 1000ms! Using a profiler I found out this time is mostly spent in NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery() (70%) and the actual query only takes 300ms. The query looks like this

```
var q = session.Query<Answer>().
        Where(a => a.User.IsExpert);
```

And the resulting sql is this:

```
select answer0_.ID          as ID0_,
   answer0_.TotalAnswer as TotalAns2_0_,
   answer0_.Rating0     as Rating3_0_,
   answer0_.Rating1     as Rating4_0_,
   answer0_.Rating2     as Rating5_0_,
   answer0_.Rating3     as Rating6_0_,
   answer0_.caseID      as caseID0_,
   answer0_.userid      as userid0_
from   Answer answer0_
   inner join Users user1_
     on answer0_.userid = user1_.ID
where  user1_.IsExpert = 1
```

Any ideas how to speed up the PrepareQuery call?

Comment: Is this the first call to `PrepareQuery` in your program? If it is, try executing an unrelated query first, and then get the timing on this query. There is a good chance that the timing is going to change drastically.